# How can I disable automatic hash password for identity .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

I can't find the way to disable automatic hash password for identity .net core. 
Because this code hashes the password automatically:

```
var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
```

Comment: And why would you want to disable it? Passwords should **always** be hashed.

Comment: Do you really want to expose all your passwords to hackers and become the next public data breach ? Are you sure your company can survive this?

Comment: Are you trying to implement password recovery? That's extremely insecure, which is why it's no longer available in .NET, not just .NET Core. The minimum used nowadays is password reset.

Comment: no guys. its just customer requirement

Comment: Final comment - hackers read SO too, because they know that insecure questions and answer will end up into production code.

Comment: @DmitryVasilyukJust3F no, it's not "just customer requirement". It's a customer death wish. Make sure you get them to understand that password reset guarantees a data breach and get them to sign that they won't hold you responsible in that case, that they take full legal responsibility - including against criminal charges. Using such insecure practices knowingly is a very bad idea. Look around for a good lawyer anyway, just in case

Comment: I hate when someone asks a valid question and the community just dumps on them instead of answering the question.  Is it a good idea?  No, in most cases not.  Doe the OP have a valid reason for asking?  Up to them.  But it's exceedingly unhelpful to attack and criticize them when you have no idea what the reason behind it is.

I actually found this looking for the same thing.  There is a valid reason behind my desire to do this (it's a private company, non-internet site and they use a simple PIN code that does not need to be hashed).  Could it be? Yes.  Should it be? Maybe.  Must it be?  No.

Comment: Please don't ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could write a class that overwrites `UserManager`

```
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<IdentityUser>
{
    public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<IdentityUser> store)
        : base(store)
    {
        this.PasswordHasher = new CustomPasswordHasher();
    }

    public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options, IOwinContext context)
    {
        var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<IdentityUser>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));         

        manager.PasswordHasher = new CustomPasswordHasher();
    }
}
```

And then override `PasswordHasher` with a new custom hasher class that inherits `PasswordHasher`.

```
internal class CustomPasswordHasher : PasswordHasher
{
    public override string HashPassword(string password)
    {
        return password;
        //return Crypto.Sha1.Encrypt(password);
    }

    public override PasswordVerificationResult VerifyHashedPassword(string hashedPassword, string providedPassword)
    {
        //var testHash = Crypto.Sha1.Encrypt(providedPassword);
        return hashedPassword.Equals(testHash) || hashedPassword.Equals(providedPassword) ? PasswordVerificationResult.Success : PasswordVerificationResult.Failed;
    }
}
```

Finally, remember, by doing that you're going to lose your database user's safety.

Comment: i know about security. its need just for customer. 
Have some trouble with your code. Didn't see this class: IdentityFactoryOptions and IOwinContext.

Comment: @DmitryVasilyukJust3F your customer is already in a hacker's list. It's not that difficult to track an SO account name back to a company and its customers. If you insist in disabling password security, make ABSOLUTELY certain that the customer releases you from any responsibility in case of a data breach. Is an insecure password reset mechanims that valuable to them?

Comment: Maybe it's missing some namespace reference.. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn613282(v=vs.108).aspx

Comment: Great solution... about to implement myself.  Thanks!

Comment: it might be worth mentioning that this works with plain .net (just did it with 4.7.2)

Answer (score 5):

Since Asp.NET Core MVC uses dependency injection to setup the Identity, all you need is just create your alternate of password hashing class:

```
public class CustomPasswordHasher : IPasswordHasher<AppUser>
{
    public string HashPassword(AppUser user, string password)
    {
        return password;
    }

    public PasswordVerificationResult VerifyHashedPassword(AppUser user, string hashedPassword, string providedPassword)
    {
        return hashedPassword.Equals(providedPassword) ? PasswordVerificationResult.Success : PasswordVerificationResult.Failed;
    }
}
```

and add:

```
services.AddScoped<IPasswordHasher<AppUser>, CustomPasswordHasher>();
```

in you mvc app statup.cs